# 2006 Toyota Corolla Jerks while coasting

Tags: troubleshooting, toyota, transmission

I have a 2006 Toyota Corolla with roughly 65k miles. Problem I'm experiencing is that every now and then she will give a couple of jerks while coasting along. Most of the time the car is traveling between 25 - 35 miles an hour. Tranmission fluid is still nice and pink and doesn't smell burnt and we just recently had the ECM replaced due to [this recall](http://www.toyota.com/recall/corolla-matrix.html).

Suggestions on where I should proceed?

UPDATE to Comments

The jerk is more of a lurch, it happens two or three times. the lurching is strong enough to notice, to start thinking "that was weird, what was that", but not strong enough to move anything on the dash. Spacing of the jerks are seconds apart.

Comment: Can you tell us what "a couple of jerks" means? Are they vibrations that you feel in the body? Is it a lurch as if the brakes or accelerator had been momentarily applied? How strong is the sensation? Is it always two? How are the jerks spaced out?

Answer (score 1):

My first suspect is the ignition system, more specifically it sounds like you have a coil breaking down. The bad part about that is that there are 4 of them and they are expensive $80 - $100 each and without specialized equipment you aren't going to be able to tell which one is bad.

Try taking it to your local auto parts store, ask them if they can hook it up to a code scanner. I doubt there will be any codes but look at the failure records and for the miss-fire counters and see if any of the cylinders have more miss-fires than the others.